# how to add separate text boxes with different background colors and titles

Tags: boxes, thesis

[Here](https://www.attoworld.de/fileadmin/user_upload/tx_attoworld/publications/thesis_phd_en_Y2015_M01_D15_LMU_FakPhys_FattahiHanieh.pdf) a phd thesis can be found which that has a feature shown in the below picture:
[image]

where two separate boxes with different colors are shown to include a title and some paragraphs in them. Does anyone know a similar template for something like this?

--------edit:

as suggested in the answers I tried the following:

```
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{246,243,226}
\colorbox{shadecolor}{%
\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth} 
    \textcolor{dark_red}{\textbf{SUMMARY: }}
         
        Some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text
        , some text, some text, some text, some text.
        , some text, some text, some text, some text.
        , some text, some text, some text, some text, some text.
        
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{239,244,243}
\colorbox{shadecolor}{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
        \textcolor{bright_blue}{\textbf{RESULTS: }}
        
        Some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text
        , some text, some text, some text, some text.
        , some text, some text, some text, some text.
        , some text, some text, some text, some text, some text.
\end{minipage}}\end{minipage}}
```

but it still doesn't look very similar:
[image]

Comment: It should be doable with the `shaded` environment, from the `framed` package, with two consecutive shaded environments, with a different value for `shadecolor`.

Answer (score 1):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\fboxsep 1em %customize it 
\begin{document}
\noindent\colorbox{olive!10}{%
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
\lipsum[1]\par\vspace{\fboxsep}
\colorbox{cyan!10}{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it as shown in the editted question, but it still doesn't look completely similar. There are some spaces missing or the space between the blue and the brown box border is bigger.

Comment: @Azerila If by missing spaces do you mean margins inside the boxes, they  are controlled by the `\fboxsep`. You can change it for all  or for each box,  but moreover you can add vertical and/or horizontal spaces to control the separation of the inner box form the inner box, as sowed in the edited answer.

Comment: @Azerila If you want a finer control of boxes style, then my advice is `texdoc tcolorbox`.